# Can't connect to localhost with firefox

Tags: firefox, localhost, utorrent

as a newbie, I am configuring uTorrent for Xubuntu 16.06 but when I try to connect to the localhost (directly typing on the web browser, I do not know other ways to do so) I have the following:

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost. /
>   Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a    few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network    connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make    sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

I can access to other websites without problems and I set the option "no proxy" on firefox settings but nothing changed.

I checked hosts configuration through terminal and this is the output:

```
less /etc/hosts 
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       lore-UX31E

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

`sudo systemctl status utorrent.service` returns me:

```
utorrent.service 
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I am following [this tutorial](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/10/25/how-to-install-utorrent-on-xubuntu-16-04-xenial-lts-linux-easy-guide/), stucked at point 8.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you want to connect to? Do you have a web server running on your local machine?

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you typed into firefox?

Comment: The default port for the uTorrent server is 8080, so the address should be something like `http://localhost:8080/gui`.

Comment: I typed exactly what @Jos suggested. I also tryed with http://localhost

Comment: Is the server running? Check with `sudo systemctl status utorrent.service` or `ps -ef|grep utserver`. Paste the output into your question.

Comment: I also tryed with `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1`. @Tilman how can I check if a web server is runing? should't I suppose to have it running since I can easily surf other websites? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: The `systemctl` command won't work with the tutorial the OP linked to. That tutorial doesn't install a systemd unit, it just unpacks the uTorrent ZIP archive into `/opt`.

Comment: As @Jos wrote, the uTorrent server provides a web server on port 8080, so you should connect using the URL `http://localhost:8080/gui`. Omitting the `:8080`will not work. To check whether _anything_ is running on that port, run `sudo netstat -antp` and look for a line with `::8080` or `0.0.0.0:8080` in the `Local Address` column. If there are none, your server is **not** running. Btw you don't need a web server on your own machine in order to surf other websites.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Why not answer your own question then and help others who might encounter the same problem?